# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have application where new rows are added to `UITableView` when more than half of content is scrolled. When adding new cells I use this:

```
[self.mainTableView beginUpdates];
[self.mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.mainTableView endUpdates];
```

Problem is that when new `cells` are added content `offset` is scrolled somewhere (whichever animation I use) and then back to old offset where I was.

I want that there is no scrolling of offset at all! So user can't even notice new cells are added if he doesn't look at scroll indicator or something like that (similar to 9gag, facebook and other apps).

When using reload data here (insted of `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`) there is also slight offset problem when `[tableView reloadData]` happens (sometimes up to 150 px so even sometimes on `reloadData` user skips one-two posts)

Really need help!!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about adding all rows to the count up front and just loading new data ready for when it needs to be displayed? Or only adding rows / reloading when scroll animations complete?

Comment: why don't you try to use  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];, (Without beginUpdate, and endUpdates)

Comment: @Basheer_CAD Because it throws me exception that rows are missing, like datasource is not uploaded with that method...

Comment: @Wain I can't do it that way if I'm planning to have 100+ posts for example... Can I?

Comment: Sure you can. Just don't go and get the data till you need it (based on scroll position). Having empty rows is low cost and should work up to thousands of rows (even though that is unlikely / not very usable on a mobile device)

Comment: @Wain Okay, I'll try that way and see how it works.